# JQuery: Does anyone know of a cool way to do this mouse over effect in jquery?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I would like to have these question marks by certain fields where if a user mouses over it brings up a window with a description of the field.

Does anyone know any good tutorials/ways to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with CSS:

```
.Help {
    display: none;
    ...
}
.Container:hover .Help {
    dislay: block;
}

<div class="Container">
    <input ... />
    <div class="Help"> ... </div>
</div>
```

This will only show the `.Help` element when its parent `.Container` is hovered over.
You would make a separate `.Container` for each input field.

You should add CSS to `.Container` and `.Help` to achieve the layout you want.

Answer (score 2):

Google ["JQuery Tooltip"](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tooltip) if you want a JQuery DOM manipulation solution, there are a plethora of plugins out there and I'm not going to list them all here.

EDIT:

By googling ["JQuery Tooltip Tutorial"](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tooltip+tutorial) I was able to find [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-better-tooltip-with-jquery-awesomeness/) tutorial from [nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/) that goes over how to author your own JQuery tooltip plugin.  Hope that helps.

Comment: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/ qTip is a nice one too! :)

Comment: Yeah, I've used qTip before and would recommend it as well.

Comment: They seem pretty cool, but i would rather not use a plug in.

Comment: Hmm, you think you can improve the wheel eh?  Well most jQuery plugins (maybe all) are open source, so the best way to figure out how to design your own solution is to see how others have approached the problem.

Comment: I'd just like to learn more about Jquery this way.

Comment: Well, if you are inexperienced disassembling a JQuery plugin might be difficult, as they are usually written to be space efficient and not human readable.  I searched the interwebs for a tutorial (Google, it's this new thing, you should check it out some time) and made an edit to my post.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".somelinkclass").hover(function() {
  // do something here when user mouses over 
}, function(){
  // do something here when the mouse leaves 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We use [jQuery Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) at work to handle our help/info for our form elements.  We found it the easiest route to go and ends up being as simple as:

```
<img src="./MyAwesomeImage.png" title="Some tool tip text"/>

    $("img[title]").tooltip({
        position: "center right",
        tipClass: "infoToolTip",
        offset: [-10, 0]
    });
```